# PostGIS to GeoJSON returning inordinate number blank records

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, null

I'm using the below code to generate GeoJSON from a Postgres95 table. When parsing out samples eg a months worth of [crime data](https://data.lacity.org/A-Safe-City/Crimes-2012-2016/s9rj-h3s6/data), which should be ~20k records for the month of March 2016, I'm getting a huge number of blank records and a few occasional populated ones.

```
     SELECT row_to_json(fc)
 FROM (
   SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
   FROM (
     SELECT
       'Feature' AS type,
       ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(t.geom,4326))::json AS geometry,
       row_to_json((SELECT p FROM (
         SELECT
          t.reported_date,
          t.report_num,
          t.occurred_date,
          t.occurred_time,
          t.agency_area_id,
          t.agency_area_name,
          t.agency_rd,
          t.crime_code,
          t.crime_desc,
          t.status_id,
          t.status_desc,
          t.location,
          t.cross_street,
          t.agency_id,
          t.sys_period_start,
          t.geom
         WHERE
              occurred_date >= '2016-03-01'
          AND occurred_date <  '2016-03-31'
         ) AS p)) AS properties
     FROM mySchema.myTable AS t
     WHERE t.crime_code is not null
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT 2000
   ) AS f
 ) AS fc;
```

This is what I get in return where 95% of the rows are returning as blank. The geom data - when parsed down to -118.0000, 33.0000 numbers can be found in the original csv data so it looks like the points are coming through, just not the properties?

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.396003723145, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.274002075195, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.304000854492, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.274002075195, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.305000305176, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "crime_desc": "BURGLARY",
        "occurred_date": "2016-03-16",
        "agency_area_id": "12",
        "reported_date": "2016-03-16",
        "cross_street": "",
        "status_id": "IC",
        "sys_period_start": "",
        "agency_area_name": "77th Street",
        "status_desc": "Invest Cont",
        "occurred_time": "800",
        "agency_id": "CA1942",
        "agency_rd": "1273",
        "crime_code": "310",
        "location": "9127 S DENKER AV",
        "geom": "0101000020E61000000000002085935DC00000006030FA4040",
        "report_num": "161209376"
    }
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.305999755859, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.277000427246, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.277000427246, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.274002075195, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.274002075195, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-118.276000976562, 33.9546012878418]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": null
}]
```

}

I thought this was a coalescing issue and added the two rows for cols that may have null or no values. After doing that I still get the same results. When looking at several rows where the GeoJSON was created I cannot find any discernible pattern.

```
       row_to_json((SELECT p FROM (
     SELECT
       COALESCE( NULLIF(t.cross_street,'') , '0' ),
       COALESCE( NULLIF(t.sys_period_start,'') , '0' ),           
      t.reported_date,
      t.report_num,
```

Here's my table:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE mySchema.crime_id_seq
  START WITH 100001
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NO MINVALUE
  NO MAXVALUE
  CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE mySchema.myTable (
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mySchema.crime_id_seq'::regclass),
reported_date     character varying,
report_num        character varying,
occurred_date     character varying,
occurred_time     character varying,
agency_area_id    character varying,
agency_area_name  character varying,
agency_rd         character varying,
crime_code        character varying,
crime_desc        character varying,
status_id         character varying,
status_desc       character varying,
location          character varying,
cross_street      character varying,
agency_id         character varying,
sys_period_start  character varying,
geom              character varying

CONSTRAINT crime_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


|reported_date|report_num|occurred_date|occurred_time|agency_area_id|agency_area_name|agency_rd crime_code|crime_desc|status_id|status_desc|location|cross_street|lon_lat|agency_id|sys_period_start|
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|2016/11/29|161228682|2016/10/14|1500|12|77th Street|1211|649|DOCUMENT FORGERY / STOLEN FELONY|IC|Invest Cont|CRENSHAW BL|54TH ST|CA1942||(-118.2983, 34.0391)|
|2016/02/01|161406199|2016/02/01|840|14|Pacific|1454|310|BURGLARY|IC|Invest Cont|4771 LA VILLA MARINA|CA1942||(-118.3515, 34.0991)|
|2016/11/17|161119346|2016/11/08|1800|11|Northeast|1127|354|THEFT OF IDENTITY|IC|Invest Cont|5730 FAYETTE ST|CA1942||(-118.3951, 34.0391)|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm replacing my answer with a working query. My schema is named different, but you should be able to sort it out.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM (
    SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
    FROM (
        SELECT
            'Feature' AS type,
            ST_AsGeoJSON(m.geom)::json AS geometry,
            row_to_json(p) as properties 
        FROM
            public.myTable as m
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                t.reported_date,
                t.report_num,
                t.occurred_date,
                t.occurred_time,
                t.agency_area_id,
                t.agency_area_name,
                t.agency_rd,
                t.crime_code,
                t.crime_desc,
                t.status_id,
                t.status_desc,
                t.location,
                t.cross_street,
                t.agency_id,
                t.sys_period_start
            FROM myTable as t
            ) AS p
        ON p.report_num = m.report_num
        WHERE 
            m.crime_code is not null 
            AND m.occurred_date >= '2016-10-01'
            AND m.occurred_date <  '2016-10-31'
        ORDER BY 1
        LIMIT 2000
    ) AS f
) AS fc;
```

This gives a result of:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -118.2983,
          34.0391
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "crime_desc": "DOCUMENT FORGERY \/ STOLEN FELONY",
        "occurred_date": "2016\/10\/14",
        "agency_area_id": "12",
        "reported_date": "2016\/11\/29",
        "cross_street": null,
        "status_id": "IC",
        "sys_period_start": null,
        "agency_area_name": "77th Street",
        "status_desc": "Invest Cont",
        "occurred_time": "1500",
        "agency_id": null,
        "agency_rd": null,
        "crime_code": "649",
        "location": "CRENSHAW BL 54TH ST",
        "report_num": "161228682"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex. When I try that I get this response: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 8:        row_to_json((SELECT * FROM (
                           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: subquery must return only one column
SQL state: 42601
Character: 248

Comment: I've updated the statement in my reply. I think you'll need to play with that inner SQL section. Mine might work!

Comment: Ok tried that and am getting this error: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 30:      FROM poursafe.ca_crime AS t

Here's the create stmt. I had to gut rows due to char limit:

`CREATE TABLE mySchema.myTable (
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mySchema.crime_id_seq'::regclass),
reported_date       character varying,
occurred_date      character varying,
crime_code           character varying,
agency_id             character varying,
sys_period_start   character varying,
geom                    character varying

CONSTRAINT crime_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

Comment: Can you add this to your question? I'd like an insert for a row, plz!

Comment: Ok rows added, had to fake - (lon,lat) with nearby coords. Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my response with a working query

Comment: Thank you Alex, that works brilliantly. I should ask for help sooner, I'd be embarrassed to say how long I've been working on it.